# CSS3 Transitions with Javascript Fallback

Tags: javascript, animation, css

Is there a javascript framework out there that will use CSS3 Transitions for effects like changing opacity or moving elements but will fall back to using javascript setInterval/setTimeout if it is not supported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the YUI 3 Transition module, it does just that.

Comment: A simple YUI3 transition: YUI().use('node', 'transition', function(Y){Y.one('#mynode').transition(opacity:0);});

Comment: lol that's simple? you should check out jquery's simple.... cause that's not simple compared to Jquery.

Comment: yes, it's simple.  It also includes the YUI sandbox to prevent outside interference of your code

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Addy Osmani's article](http://addyosmani.com/blog/css3transitions-jquery/). It is a good summary of the current solutions with jQuery, specifically:

- [jquery.transition.js](https://github.com/louisremi/jquery.transition.js) by Louis-Rémi Babé
- [jQuery.animate-enhanced.js](https://github.com/benbarnett/jQuery-Animate-Enhanced) by Ben Barnett

Answer (score 2):

You could look at using http://www.modernizr.com/

Comment: that looks good to detect support for transitions. i also noticed mootools has: http://mootools.net/docs/core/Fx/Fx.Tween and http://mootools.net/forge/p/fx_tween_css3

Comment: Modernizr is the most effective way of feature checking at the moment and at 3kb, it's really lightweight (compared to Mootools)

Comment: LOL of course Modernizr is smaller than MooTools it's a detection kit not a Framework for dom manipulation, class abstraction and serverside scripting

Comment: modernizr (obviously) does not provide a JavaScript fallback.

Comment: No it doesn't but it does come bundled with yepnope which allows you to check and load javascript fallbacks where you want.

Answer (score 1):

One of my colleagues has written a micro library offering a limited JS fallback to Transitions: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2011/12/06/css3-transitions.aspx

```
TRANSITIONSHELPER.computeCubicBezierCurveInterpolation = function (t, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    // Extract X (which is equal to time here)
    var f0 = 1 - 3 * x2 + 3 * x1;
    var f1 = 3 * x2 - 6 * x1;
    var f2 = 3 * x1;

    var refinedT = t;
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var refinedT2 = refinedT * refinedT;
        var refinedT3 = refinedT2 * refinedT;

        var x = f0 * refinedT3 + f1 * refinedT2 + f2 * refinedT;
        var slope = 1.0 / (3.0 * f0 * refinedT2 + 2.0 * f1 * refinedT + f2);
        refinedT -= (x - t) * slope;
        refinedT = Math.min(1, Math.max(0, refinedT));
    }

    // Resolve cubic bezier for the given x
    return 3 * Math.pow(1 - refinedT, 2) * refinedT * y1 +
            3 * (1 - refinedT) * Math.pow(refinedT, 2) * y2 +
            Math.pow(refinedT, 3);
};
```

Maybe it could be enough or a good base to achieve what's you're looking for?

Bye,

David

Answer (score 0):

To sum it up, there are some plugins for big frameworks (see other answers):

- jQuery ([jquery.transition.js](https://github.com/louisremi/jquery.transition.js) and [jquery.animate-enhanced.js](https://github.com/benbarnett/jQuery-Animate-Enhanced))
- [MooTools](http://mootools.net/forge/p/fx_tween_css3)

Other frameworks already use CSS transitions where possible:

- [YUI](https://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/transition/)
- [rightjs](http://rightjs.org/)

Are there any micro-libraries?

Answer (score 0):

sadly none of these alternatives seem to allow you to use the easings, like bounce.

My attempt to use animate-enhanced moved the element an inch and then just removed it. I really would like to keep the bounce instead of just a cubic or linear easing.