# Does CSS3 use JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, rendering, css-transitions

How does CSS3 work? Does it use JavaScript behind the scenes in the browser?
Because the transition effects are of JavaScript quality! Is CSS just styling?

I know my question is a little weird - my teacher asked me this today.

Comment: It's implemented in code inside the rendering engine, just like the rest of CSS.

Comment: I just now the simple answer. sorry. Thats why I don't use the answer field

Comment: I dont know who voted this as "primarily opinion based", your opinion wont change the fact that css3 isn't dependent on js, so the close reason is invalid.

Answer (score 6):

[CSS is rendered by browsers' native layout rendering engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28Cascading_Style_Sheets%29). It doesn't involve JavaScript, at least not in common browsers.

"JavaScript quality" is a bit of a non-sequitur. These rendering engines ([most often written](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browser_engines) in performant languages like C or C++, if it matters) are unbelievably optimized, more than you'd likely get even from the most optimized, JITted JavaScript.

Comment: So the rendering engine must use the same algorithms as of javascript?

Comment: @jackkorbin: I don't understand what you've said, but I think the answer is no.

Answer (score 2):

No.

The css3 makes browser itself render the anmiation for you hence it's faster and hence it's not supported in older browsers.

If you like to see the real difference between css3 and javascript animations you can take a look at this video which has nice explanation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E72WV7EjWjE

Answer (score 1):

No, CSS does not use Javascript behind the scenes

Javascript and CSS both have ways to make the browser render something. They are unrelated to each other for the most part besides the fact that they achieve similar goals and can (kind of) interact with each other

CSS3, unlike what one answer here suggests, is *not* always faster at rendering when compared to focused Javascript libraries like GSAP, Velocity.js, or some other library. You can look up either library and see the performance tests comparing them all. I assume he says that because it is generally faster at rendering than jQuery and most vanilla Javascript animations

The only case in which you might could say CSS is generating Javascript is in the case of supporting older browsers that do not support CSS3's animations and transitions. They often use feature detection and implement Javascript fallbacks if CSS is not supported. For more information check out [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096332/css3-transitions-with-javascript-fallback) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15683067/jquery-fallback-for-css3-transition)

In short, CSS does not use Javascript in modern browsers to render or else it would be slower than javascript, due to the extra parsing of the CSS

Answer (score -2):

HTML attribute STYLE or style object or CSS this are 3 ways for same thing.
But browser can support this ways different.

Javascript style object.

HTML CSS inside STYLE Tag.

HTML Style attibute inside HTML tag like < DIV >

Support og style object may be better than CSS inside STYLE tag.

e.g. IE  HTML XHTML Reference see msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh772960%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

e.g. IE Windows Internet Explorer API Reference  see msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh772374%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: This isn't talking about how to style elements, rather how CSS transitions and animations work